# Visual Studio for Applications (VBA) - Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, vba, microsoft-office

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en VisualBasic for Applications (VBA), dentro de Excel.

Teniendo en cuenta el siguiente código, busco saber como podría hacer para establecer un rango predeterminado, en lugar de ejecutar la Macro y manualmente seleccionar el rango que deseo.

```
Sub BlankLine()
'Updateby20150203
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set WorkRng = WorkRng.Columns(1)
xLastRow = WorkRng.Rows.Count
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For xRowIndex = xLastRow To 1 Step -1
    Set Rng = WorkRng.Range("A" & xRowIndex)
    If Rng.value < "1.560" Then
        Rng.Offset(1, 1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Rng.Offset(1, 0).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

A continuación dejo una imagen de apoyo:

[image: Ejecución de la Macro]

Espero puedan apoyarme, buen día y gracias.

Comment: Pero establecer un rango predeterminado que tú hayas seleccionado? O buscas que el rango predeterminado sea siempre el mismo?

Comment: `Set WorkRng = WorkRng.Columns(1)` ahí es donde tienes que poner el rango predeterminado que quieras

Comment: @Esei muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me ha sido de gran utilidad